# sending unique pages to groups of users

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

i need to show an HTML page to users
but every group of users will see parts of this page differently.

for now i have a JSP page in its basic form
and i need that when a user clicks on a button
everyone in his "group" will be notified. say by painting the button blue.

what i thought is that every browser will ask the servlet if a button was clicked
and once a user clicks a button the answer will be "true"

the problem is that EVERYONE gets notified. also users not in his group. all the buttons are painted.

i think it is because i add a class "blue" to the button and then when the other users ask, the JSP is changed (with the class blue to the button)

Comment: Can you post your code checking the user group and the jsp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to identify users that are requests your jsp.
Basically there are two ways to achieve this :

- using HttpSession, @see [tutorial session](http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Servlet-Tutorial/Servlet-Tutorial-Session-Tracking.html)
- using URL parameter, @see [tutorial url parameters](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/servlets/parameters.shtml)

As for me ill use session for this :

//ex. for every user in group add a identifier in session.

```
group 1 => request.getSession().addAttribute("groupId","green");

group 2 => request.getSession().addAttribute("groupId","blue");
```

//then in jsp

```
<input type="button" class='<%=request.getSession().getAttribute("groupId")%>'></input>
```

Comment: so for every button i need to add a jsp attribute to check if the groupId attr is set on the button? is it possible to make this in js? in a .js file?

Comment: if you want you can do that, but that is pointless..
just make css classes for every Group, and apply them were you identified a user from specified group..
as in my example just create a css class "green" and "blue" and style it as you want. users from "blue" group will recieve input with css class "blue", "green" => green, etc...